# How to call servet when open .jsp file

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I created a Slide Show with jQuery. It's connected to database with servlet. So, I have to call servlet to run the Slide Show. I tried to call servlet from index.jsp with include but it hasn't found SlideShow servlets. I tried to use Ajax to call servlet but it can't display Slide Show. Please how to call?

Answer (score 2):

Just call the servlet directly by URL instead of the JSP file, do the job in `doGet()` method and finally let the servlet forward the request to the JSP to let it generate and send the HTML stuff.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/index"})
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Do your job here.
        // ...
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Invoke this by http://example.com/contextname/index instead of http://example.com/contextname/index.jsp and put the JSP in `/WEB-INF` folder to prevent it from being opened directly without intervention of the servlet.

You can do the preprocessing job in `doGet()` method and store the data as request attribute. E.g.

```
List<Data> data = dataService.list();
request.setAttribute("data", data); // It'll be available by ${data} in JSP.
```

As to the Ajax story, perhaps you're simply implementing it wrongly. You can find some examples here: [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

#### See also:

- [Our servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)